# Importing selected .csv files in R out of multiple .csv files present in a folder

Tags: r, csv

I have multiple .csv files in a folder, named as Pt4_1, Pt4_2, Pt5_1, Pt5_2....and so on. Is there a way in R to import a selected files. To my knowledge (definitely very limited) there seems to be a way of importing a .csv files such as:

read.table("Pt4_1.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

However, this dont seem to be of any help to me as I have to import multiple .csv files as a result writing the above said syntax multiple times (tedious).

Can any one suggest a way so I am able to write a loop and call multiple .csv files accordingly? Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the files are in the working directory and they have a definite pattern, for example, the below code will select files that begin (`^`) with `Pt` followed by digits (`\\d+`), underscore (`_`), digits (`\\d+`) and the `.csv`.  Read the files in a "list" using `lapply` and `read.csv`.

```
 files <- list.files(pattern='^Pt\\d+_\\d+.csv')
 lst <- lapply(files, read.csv,header=TRUE)
```

Another option if the files are very big would be to use `fread` from `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 lst1 <- lapply(files, fread)
```

#### Update

You may be able to create a function to create the pattern.

```
 filePat <- function(d1, d2){
      sprintf('Pt%d_%d.csv', d1, d2)
     }

filePat(2,3)
#[1] "Pt2_3.csv"
```

Comment: This list all the files with pattern '^Pt\d+_\d+.csv'. Is there a way to access a particular .csv files say, Pt5_2. I am looking for something like this:

csvRead('FilePath' + "\" + "Pt" + string(i+3) + "_" + string(j) + ".csv", ',') here i=2 and j=2.

Running this command on platform such as Scilab would read Pt5_2.csv file.

Comment: If you want a particular file, why don't you just use the `filename` instead of pattern. I may have misunderstood your question.  Do you want to read files `Pt5_2`, Pt_5_3` etc....

Comment: Deepak, the point of this solution is to use the elements of `files` in a loop. Akrun used `lapply` but you could also write `for(fname in files) read.csv(fname)` and so on.

Comment: @akrun I don't want to hardcode the filename as I might process any of the .csv files (available in directory) as per the logic (for e.g., one time Pt4_1 and the other time Pt8_2 or so on). Thus, I am looking for something where I can set the prefix to "Pt" and change the following digits such as 4_1 or 8_2 to call the .csv files. In a nutshell, I should be able to modify the .csv filename dynamically. Appreciate your help, meanwhile I googling the solution to this problem.

Comment: @Deepak So, are you saying that you want to sometimes process only `Pt4_1` file?  Why don't you use `paste`?

Comment: @Deepak Not sure I understand you correctly.  But, I think `paste` or `sprintf` would be beneficial. `sprintf('Pt%d_%d.csv', 2,3)`

Comment: No, I want to pull a specific file from the directory but not necessarily Pt4_1. So the solution could be If i can change the name of a file to be read dynamically such as: Pt[i]_[j], where i and j are the numbers. For e.g., If now i want to read Pt4_1.csv file I may define i as 4 and j as 1.

Comment: @akrun Your update solves my issue, struggled a lot today and seems very simple now. Cheers, Thanks a lot!!